# CentOS 8 yum/dnf update fails over internet connection

Tags: yum, curl, centos8, dnf

I have a **squid proxy server** on **CentOS 8** and whenever I install a package it returns lines along the following:

> [MIRROR] git-core-doc-2.27.0-1.el8.noarch.rpm: Curl error (3): URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL for //Unfocus the text-area./Packages/git-core-doc-2.27.0-1.el8.noarch.rpm [ malformed]
> [MIRROR] git-2.27.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Curl error (3): URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL for //There was some user input missing - don't continue./Packages/git-2.27.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm [ malformed]
> [MIRROR] git-core-2.27.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Curl error (3): URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL for //There was some user input missing - don't continue./Packages/git-core-2.27.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm [ malformed]
> [MIRROR] git-core-doc-2.27.0-1.el8.noarch.rpm: Curl error (3): URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL for //There was some user input missing - don't continue./Packages/git-core-doc-2.27.0-1.el8.noarch.rpm [ malformed]
> [FAILED] git-2.27.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: No more mirrors to try - All mirrors were already tried without success

> The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
> You can remove cached packages by executing 'yum clean packages'.
> Error: Error downloading packages:
> Cannot download Packages/git-2.27.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: All mirrors were tried

I tried installing `git` as testing as I was able to update the server last night with no problems. I tried the following set ups:

1. Proxy server alone, connected to the internet - install failed
2. The Proxy server connected to another proxy server configured in `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf` - install succeeded
3. Another server using the squid proxy settings - install failed

The weird thing is I cannot do `curl` on the Proxy Server but I can do `wget`, `ping`, `tracepath`, etc. BUT if I do a `curl` on another server that uses the proxy server, it returns something.

I also tried the following commands:

- `yum clean all`
- `yum makecache`

I don't know if it is a server issue or a network issue since I never made configuration changes to the server nor the squid proxy after it was set up. Thanks

Comment: The context `for //Unfocus the text-area./Packages/git-core-doc-2.27.0-1.el8.noarch.rpm [ malformed] ` suggests that somebody used copy and paste to configure a package URI or yum repository and didn’t copy the actual URL but copied some mark-up instead. That is obviously not a valid download URI

Comment: Any idea how to fix it? it doesn't occur on other proxies

Comment: Start by looking at the configuration of the squid proxy.

Comment: Well, I tried running the command with the squid service disabled and the same thing still happens. We can perform `composer` updates using the proxy but not yum update.